# Java - How to remove elements from a Point Array and correctly return new fixed Array

Tags: java, arrays, return, point

Write a method named removeSomePoints. This method takes an array of Points, and returns a new array of points that is the same as the original array, except that it removes all points that have x- and y-coordinates that differ by less than 20. In other words, the returned array will probably have a smaller size than the original array. This method should leave the original array untouched. To clarify: If any of the following points were in the original array, they would not be in the array that is returned.

100 90 (x and y differ by 10)

90 100 (x and y differ by 10)

3 22 (x and y differ by 19)

On the other hand, any of the following points would be in the array that is returned:

100 80 (x and y differ by 20)

80 100 (x and y differ by 20)

2 25 (x and y differ by 23)

My code:

```
      public static Point[] removeSomePoints(Point[] arr)  {

   int count = 0;      
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (Math.abs(arr[i].getX() - arr[i].getY()) > 19) {
        count++;
      }
     }

    Point[] finalArr = new Point[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < finalArr.length; i++) {
      if (Math.abs(arr[i].getX() - arr[i].getY()) > 19) {
           finalArr[i] = arr[i];
      }

 }

   return finalArr;
}
```

I've also tried it with this code using ArrayLists:

```
 public static Point[] removeSomePoints(Point[] arr) {
    ArrayList<Point> pointList = new ArrayList<Point>(Arrays.asList(arr));
    for (int i = 0; i < pointList.size(); i++) {
        if (Math.abs(pointList.get(i).getX() - pointList.get(i).getY()) < 20) {
            pointList.remove(i);

        }
    }
    Point[] finalArr = new Point[pointList.size()];
    finalArr = pointList.toArray(finalArr);

    return finalArr;
}
```

Neither of the above blocks of code work for what my finished return array should be, many of the points (such as Point(6, 3) are left in when their absolute difference is certainly less than 19).

Can't seem to figure out what is going wrong. It is returning an array but it doesn't change anything. In my main method I have:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter name of file containing Points: ");
    String fileName = scan.next();
    Point[] myPoints = readPoints(fileName);
    sortPoints(myPoints); // works fine
    writePoints(myPoints, "sorted.txt");  //works fine up until this point
    removeSomePoints(myPoints)       //doesn't work, effects below method call
    writePoints(myPoints, "sortedAndRemoved.txt");
    new PointDisplay(myPoints, 10, false);  //works fine, pre-written class
```

I'm asking what is wrong with my removeSomePoints method and what can be done differently. How do I correctly remove and return the Point Array with all points with absolute difference of 19 and lower removed?

Comment: this is a different question - it's asking about hy the rest of the program isn't taking his function into account, not about the function itself.

Comment: Ok, ignore my comment and close vote, I see the OP has moved on to another part of the same question.

Answer (score 1):

you're returning a new array but not setting the original array to the returned value. You should change

```
removeSomePoints(myPoints)       //doesn't work, effects below method call
```

to

```
myPoints=removeSomePoints(myPoints);       //works now
```

That should solve your problem.

Note: this is different than sortPoints because you sort the array in-place but you make a new array to remove the points.

Comment: click the green hollow checkmark on the left of this answer to mark it as correct